# Tester not able to install app using testFlight

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

An internal user who could install and test a couple of early versions of my app, can't install the new version on her device. I didn't change certificates/profiles in the new version. This is her experience with the new version:

The download has been unsuccessful, so I cannot try the current version of the app. It shows the update in Test Flight (version 1.3.2 (6)), and shows it downloading, but then I get an error message that says "Unable to Download App: myApp".

What can be the cause of this problem?

Comment: I have some testers with the same problem. Possibly an Apple issue?

Comment: I actually contacted Apple regarded this issue. I am waiting for their reply, and will update you once I received a response from them.

Comment: This kind of problem occurs because of the size of your ipa file. I faced the same issue. If it is above 50mb then try to download it through your wi-fi not from your mobile connection.

Comment: Thanks Manthan, the size of my app is below 20 mb. Nonetheless, I will tell her try your suggestion and see if it works.

Comment: Manthan, you were right, she were able to download and install the app successfully with wifi. If you post this solution as an answer, I will accept it. Thanks.

Comment: @Manthan your answer was right, post it as a solution :)

Comment: @DARKMATTER: Glad your problem is solved.

Comment: @Tokn: Glad your problem is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of problem occurs because of the size of your **IPA** file. I faced the same issue.

If it is above 50mb then try to download it through your **WI-fi** not from your mobile connection.

For best practices, we should always download an **IPA** file through wifi to avoid this kind of issues.

It helped me.

Hope it works for someone else also.

Comment: I'm having the unable to download app problem and the only net connection I have is through wifi (iPad) so while wifi may solve the problem for some people it is not necessarily the solution for every instance. My IPA is < 5MB so I don't think it is about size.

Comment: Please check your device is added in the provisioning profile.

Comment: Thanks @manthan, but under the new Apple TestFlight system, users devices no longer have to be in the provisioning profile. We were at wits end and while waiting (still waiting) to hear back from Apple we threw a hail Mary and submitted another build - identical except we incremented the CFBundle version. It installs for our testers just fine!

Comment: That is nice to hear @TonyAdams. You can also user diawi to send adhoc to your clients. It is also easy to use.

Comment: it could be super handy to have an alternative means to deploy apps for testing. Thank you very much for letting us know about diawi! धन्यवाद

Answer (score 0):

In my case was because the user for some reason was unchecked in **iTunes Connect**.

I checked the user and I sent the invitation again and the user could already download the app